# Disassemble raw AArch64 binary using LLVM tools

Tags: llvm, disassembly, objdump

I can disassemble raw binary file using the following command:

```
> aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -m aarch64 -b binary -D file.bin
```

Can I achieve the same effect with `llvm-objdump` and how? Maybe any other tool from LLVM toolchain?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found to do this using only LLVM tools is to first `objcopy` the binary into an ELF and then `objdump` the ELF.

#### Convert the file

```
llvm-objcopy -I binary -O elf64-littleaarch64 --rename-section=.data=.text,code file.bin file.elf
```

Let's go through this option-by-option:

- `-I binary`: specifies that the input is in raw binary, rather than ELF, form.
- `-O elf64-littleaarch64` (LLVM 10+<sup>1</sup>): specifies that the binary is to be interpreted as AArch64 machine code.
- `--rename-section=.data=.text,code`: specifies that the section named `.data` that automatically gets created when copying from a binary file should instead be named `.text` and marked as executable code. This allows disassembly with `-d` to work later.

#### Disassemble the file

```
llvm-objdump -d file.elf
```

This one's pretty self-explanatory (and the same as you'd write with GNU `objdump`). `-d` says to disassemble all code sections, and the only code section is the one that we marked using `--rename-section` in the previous step.

---

<sup>1</sup>This command is for LLVM 10 and above. LLVM 10 has removed the binary-specific `-B` option in favor of specifying your output target with the `-O` option. For LLVM 9 and below, you'd use `-B aarch64`.

Comment: When running `llvm-objdump` you can specify the section to disassemble with `--section .data`, which means you can drop the `--rename-section=.data=.text,code`.

Comment: For those wanting to disassemble ARM thumb code, you can use something like `--triple armv7m`.